# How to script preserving application state in Frank?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewstate, frank

I am trying to test an iOS application with Frank that uses application state preservation.

How can I get Frank to force the application to save its application state and restart the application loading its state?

BTW Restarting the simulator resets the application preserved state.